# Every superset of an infinite set is infinite proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**This is my proof:**

Let X be an infinite set and let Y be a superset of X , i.e. , X$\subseteq$Y.
Then (by Dekekind definition) there exist and injection $f:X\to X$ such that $f(X)\neq X$.
We define a function $g:Y\to Y$ by:
$$g(y) =
\begin{cases}
f(y) & \text{if⠀⠀} y \in X \\
y & \text{if⠀⠀}y \in Y-X
\end{cases}$$
Now if we show that $g:Y\to Y$ is an injection too , our proof ends .
To proof injection,we must proof injection for two cases of $g(y)$ separately.

**Case 1:**
Thats obvious because of the question's hypothesis .

**Case 2:**
$$y∈Y-X⇒g(y)=y$$
So for $a,b∈Y-X$:
$$[g(a)=g(b)] ⇒[a=b]$$
Thus the injection is proven.

**But when I showed this proof to my teacher, he said that you must add this to your proof:**
If ⠀[ $a ∈ X$ and $ b ∈ Y-X$ ] ⇒ $[ a\neq b ]$

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show in general: $a,b \in Y$ and $a \neq b$ then $g(a)\neq g(b)$.

Because of the definition of $g$ in cases depending on $a \in X$ or $a \in Y\setminus X$ we have a priori $4$ cases:

- $a \in X, b \in X$. Covered by $f$ being injective.
- $a \in X, b \in Y \setminus X$. Clear as $g(a) = f(a) \in X$ and $g(b)=b \in Y\setminus X$. So $g(a) \neq g(b)$ (or else $b=g(b)= g(a) \in X$ contradiction.)
- $ a \in Y\setminus X$, $b \in X$, same argument as previous case with $a$, $b$ swapped. Symmetry...
- $ a \in Y\setminus X$, $b \in Y\setminus X$: clear as $g(b)=b, g(a)=a$ in that case..

But all cases are needed, and you just did the first and last. Your teacher pointed out the middle two (with implicit symmetry use).

Answer (score 0):

It is a necessary case. It is entirely trivial, but must be pointed out to have a full and complete proof.

The definition of injectivity says that if we have $a,b\in Y$ such that $g(a)=g(b)$, then we should have $a=b$. To study this, we split up into *every possible case*: first $a,b\in X$, second $a,b\in Y-X$, and finally the possibility that one of them is in $X$ and one of them isn't.

Which is to say, if it's an exercise or an exam problem or something similar, you ought to do it. If not, then it's basically up to you and how much you trust your readers to figure out the missing piece on their own.